# How to blur rest of the table while focus on a row of antd-table

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd

I have an ant-d table in which some rows will have errors and edit them options, when the user clicks edit on this error rows, input field opens inside the row for correction, and I want rest of the table rows to go blur in the background during this operation until save. Is it possible to do so for ant-d table?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, read the Table docs: https://ant.design/components/table/ especially the render & onExpand props

Comment: ok, I read the docs, and what I can understand is I can write a customised function to highlight selected row or fade rest of the table with html, and call this function at the time of edit(using idea of expandIcon prop). Can you help me with how to fade rest of the table with html.

Comment: The same state "isBlured" needs to apply on the elements you want to be blurred, specifically just `style` the table depending on state as mentioned in docs.